# Google analytics IDFA usage on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload application update on itunes, but it does identify my app as using IDFA although i am not serving any ads in the app !

i found this link on google dev site  :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#headers

however , i do not enable IDFA settings 
how disable IDFA usage  ?

shall i remove lib 
libAdIdAccess.a
AdSupport.framework

does apple approved usage of IDFA for tracking ?

Comment: Apple lets you use IDFA depending on the intention you have (currently you have to specify what you use it for). If the system didn't change recently, you have to manually enable IDFA tracking inside the GA dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems it was issue in my google analytic settings , where i have enabled by mistake advanced analytic like age , gender etc in my google analytic dashboard

disabling this config resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Even i faced same issue, simply remove libAdIdAccess.a AdSupport.framework from xcode and push to App Store. My App got approved by apple by doing this. 
Note: Disable advanced analytic like age , gender etc in google analytic dashboard